# How to mark app update as Immediate, or Flexible(in-app updates API)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack, in-app-update

I am trying to release an app update, but am unable to find how to mark the update as Immediate or Flexible while uploading the new api through the play console

The logic for the various types of updates is already written in my code

Answer (score 3):

There is no option in Google Play for choose Flexible or Immediate update. Developer must trigger selection in code.

> Its already asking in Google Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133299031)
>
> It is up to the developer to choose which type of update is invoked.
> The mode is determined by the app in code.
> Please see https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#start_update